# How do i get Firefox to send HTTP Referer data to an embedded flash player?

Tags: http, firefox

I want to stream some videos, and have it all done up for flash, but don't want them to be accessed by outsiders, so i have the server set so that only if the right http_referer is set that it works. but firefox doesn't work properly for some reason.

the most frustrating thing about this is that it even works in IE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

scott

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` after typing `about:config` in Firefox. As per http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader:

0 - Never send the Referer header or set document.referrer.

1 - Send the Referer header when clicking on a link, and set document.referrer for the following page.

2 - Send the Referer header when clicking on a link or loading an image, and set document.referrer for the following page.